# Execute a aspx page from windows application and get data returned

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi am working on a windows application in which i have to call a aspx page which  read values from database and convert it into an XML.I have no clue how to call a aspx page and make it return a value to the calling windows application.I tried using Web request method it doesnot return anything.Please suggest me a idea how to do this

Comment: Better try WCF method and get the value from that, Even u can use the same WCF method for aspx page

Comment: @pvaju896 can u please provide me a example or any useful link

Comment: Do you control the web-application or is it on a remote server?

Comment: @TimSchmelter i have control over the webapplication.As of now am trying it on my local machine

Comment: @karthi - try creating a visual studio WCF application give the connection string and write method in it(i mean simple WCF method that returns XML string as you need)for retrieving the DB values and create Xml using serialization class. Same time create a service reference from your windows appl. and add namespace and use the WCF service- call it & get the output of it. CHECK OUT MSDN OR OTHER SITES TO LEARN WCF STARTUPS(Just create and run the WCF APP to make Service hosted -then give reference).Hope this helps. I dont think i need to put any code here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use WebClient, something like this :

this is a sitemap XML generated by HttpModule that intercepts requests for XML files:

```
  WebClient wc = new WebClient();
  string smap = wc.DownloadString("http://www.antoniob.com/sitemap.xml");
```

And this is a theoretical aspx that returns XML

```
  WebClient wc = new WebClient();
  string smap = wc.DownloadString("http://www.somesite.com/GetXml.ashx");
```

There is no difference in the call, except of course in address

**On Server side** (asp.net app), it would be better to use ASHX handler since is more suited for returning XML, In your ASP.NET application add new item, and choose generic handler :

[image]

and here is the code for GetXml.ashx handler that will return sample XML from App_Data folder :

```
  public class GetXml : IHttpHandler
  {    
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
      context.Response.ContentType = "text/xml";
      string xml = File.ReadAllText(context.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/sample.xml"));
      context.Response.Write(xml);
      context.Response.End();    
    }

    public bool IsReusable
    {
      get
      {
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: am not talking about downloading an xml file.I need to run a aspx page which creates xml on the fly.and get that xml file in my windows application.Thanks

Comment: there is no difference, only in address. In my case this is not static XML file, it's generated on the fly and served as a request. I will change url if you will feel better :)

Comment: thanks for your Quick response.Am still confused..How to return xml from webpage.Should i put the code in page load or some where else.Can u please explain it in steps

Comment: Oh, I was thinking that you have web app part solved, I will update my answer